# Arranging 3 div's in a container and one with auto height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to arrange 3 divs side by  using float:left, there is fixed height for two div's child1 and child3, but there is no height for child2, i need the child2 div height as the same height of the container div.

```
 <div id="container">
   <div id="child1">Child1</div>
   <div id="child2">Child2</div>
   <div id="child3">Child3</div>
 <div>


 #container
 {
 margin-left: 3px;
 padding: 10px 0px;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 500px;
 background:yellow;
 overflow:hidden;
 }

 #child1
 {
 float:left;
 width:100px;
 height:300px;
 background:green;
 }


 #child2
 {
 float:left;
 width:100px;
 height:auto;
 background:cyan;
 }

 #child3
 {
 float:left;
 width:100px;
 height:400px;
 background:red;
 }
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ksxL/2/

Comment: `display: table;` is the answer

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/2ksxL/3/

Comment: you can use javascript
document.getElementById("child2").style.height = document.getElementById("container").offsetHeight+"px";
or use padding-bottom:100%

Comment: Or this? http://jsfiddle.net/2ksxL/4/
Make height of child2 100% and specify height to container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't define any height for container, the container height is going to depend on the max height that's been defined to the `#childX`. In this case, `#child3`. So what you can do is compare the height of both `#chidl1` and `#child3` and set the height of `#child2` to the max one via this little jQuery.

```
var highestCol = Math.max($('#child1').height(),$('#child3').height());
$('#child2').height(highestCol);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2ksxL/5/)**

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `#container {display: flex;}`, but that does not have awesome support in IE (http://caniuse.com/flexbox). If you need more support you will have to come up with a jQuery solution that can find the height of the container and give it to #child2.